# Search a node in array of children nodes in n-ary tree

Tags: python, tree, recursive-datastructures

I'm stuck quith this issue from 2 weeks.

I have a basic treenode class in Python:

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data= data
        self.children = []
        self.parent = None
```

then I have a generic recursive search function:

```
def find_node(node, data):
    if node.data == data:
        return node

    if len(node.children)>0:
        for child in node.children:
            find_node(child, data)
```

I can't figure out why Python is searching only in the first occurrency of each "data" I pass to the find_node function.

I'm passing always the root node and then the string that identifies the node I'm looking for.

Really banging my head on the wall.

Comment: it returns None

Comment: what is data's type? str? int? maybe you should use is instead of ==

Comment: it's a simple string. I'll give a shot, ty. 

Nope. It didn't solve.

Comment: are you sure you added children properly? seems that you dont have add_child function

Comment: you don't need an ``add_child`` function you can just ``node.children.append(child)``

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems in your code the first is that you are not returning the node if the function is called recursively. The second is that if you if you just use `return find_node(child, data)` the function will return on first pass but you only want to return if a node was found within the recursion function. Therefor you have to change

```
find_node(child, data)
```

with something like

```
potNode = find_node(child, data)
if not potNode is None:
    return potNode
```

Comment: Great, I understood and now it works, i tweaked a little bit your if with a more straightforward: 

```
potNode = find_node(child, data)
if potNode: 
   return potNode
```

And it seems to work properly. 

Thankyou very much

Comment: @DarioWoollover, you should then mark this answer as accepted.